# SSLPeerUnverifiedException while using self signed SSL certificate

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have create a slef-signed SSL certificate for testing purpose. It works fine when I open `https://localhost` from browser and now I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned) guide for adding my own `TrustManager` in Android.

When I try to connect to server using `IP address` of my machine it throws

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 192.168.10.3 not verified:
```

While I was able to solve it using `HostnameVerifier`

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
        return hostname.trim().equals("192.168.10.3") || hv.verify(hostname, session);
    }
};
```

but still I want to know **what am I missing here?** **Am I still configuring it properly by using custom `HostnameVerifier`?** Here is the output of my 
certificate

```
I/System.out: ca=C=PK, L=Islamabad, O=Self, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16176D616C6C617564696E71617A6940676D61696C2E636F6D, CN=https://192.168.10.3
```

I am running `openssl` server by using following command

```
openssl s_server -key rsa.key -cert allaudin.pem -accept 4000 -WWW
```

Comment: `https://` prefix shouldn't be part of the common name

Comment: It doesn't work without prefix too. I have tried that.

Comment: refer to this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539408/using-ip-address-for-common-name-in-server-certificate-does-not-work-in-android

Comment: Try using the IP in a SAN field of the certificate or in the dNSName field, instead.  I'm pretty sure one of these worked for me in the past.  Post if it works and I'll convert this to an answer.

Comment: How can I add SAN field?

Answer (score 1):

You can using [Alternative Names](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/master/src/test/resources/openssl.cnf#L22-L28) for IP Address in self-signed SSL Certificate file.

There is a bash file that I have wrote on [github](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/master/src/test/resources/x509.sh) to generate self-signed certificate within alternative names, you can copy the [openssl.cnf](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/master/src/test/resources/openssl.cnf#L22-L28) and customize your openssl config. if want to using an existing **private key**, the bash file should be this:

```
#!/bin/bash
KEY_FILE="server.key"
#######################################################
## Remove all generated files                        ##
#######################################################

rm -f  server.crt keystore.p12 keystore.jks

#######################################################
## generate x509 certificate                         ##
#######################################################

openssl req -new -x509 -key $KEY_FILE -sha256 -out server.crt -days 730 -config openssl.cnf
openssl x509 -in server.crt -text -noout

#######################################################
## adding self-signed certificate into jks key store ##
#######################################################

PASSWORD="password"
openssl pkcs12 -export -name test -in server.crt -inkey $KEY_FILE -out keystore.p12 -password "pass:$PASSWORD"
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstorepass $PASSWORD -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias test -storepass $PASSWORD

#######################################################
## Remove pkcs12 keystore                            ##
#######################################################
rm -f keystore.p12
```

using `openssl x509 -in **.crt -text -noout` to see whether having alternative names in self-signed certificate file. the alternative names in [server.crt](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/master/src/test/resources/server.crt) are:

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
        IP Address:127.0.0.1
```

**AND** having a [TestCase](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/master/src/test/java/test/java/net/HttpsServerTest.java#L51-L70) according to [Android unknown certificate authority](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa) has been wrote in java8 & junit5, if you want to test in Android you need make some transformations.

Comment: @mallaudin The TestCase failed in android? I'm not having installed Android Environment in my computer. you can copy the TestCase and runing it in Android.

Comment: @mallaudin you can using `openssl x509 -in **.crt -text -noout` to see whether having alternative names in a certificate file.

Comment: @mallaudin you can find and download all of the files on [github](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/commit/04d0054745f1ea5cd2095d86de2eea7c957cc5b1). and all of the test s is passed in java Platform, I think it could pass in Android.

Comment: I don't have any alternate name in the output

Comment: @mallaudin you can see more details in [openssl.cnf](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/master/src/test/resources/openssl.cnf#L22-L28). the selection rows is how to config alternative names in certificate. adding alternative  names you must use a config file.